# Sqlite how to check all contains about one table

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Hello my question is about iOS + SQLite.

I've built one application in iOS easy. I have one screen where I have 11 textfield and I want to check if exists one name in one table of database, namely, if one registry of table exist in this table.

```
- (IBAction)checkRegistry:(id)sender {
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from players"]
    // i don't know that to make this check ....
}
```

Comment: Can´t you just check if query is not null and then do somethings if it´s not?

Comment: That example is not worth because i check if one name exists and if exists check other parameter if can play.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to search for a record is to let the database do this:

```
SELECT injuries FROM players WHERE name = 'Paco';
```

This query returns nothing if no such row exists, or one column with the desired value(s):

```
int rc;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT injuries FROM players WHERE name = ?;",
                        -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    log("error: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return ...;
}
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "Paco", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
    // no Paco found
} else if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
    int injuries = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    ...
} else {
    log("error: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return ...;
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: Yes, this query is very easy but i need combine with objective-C, here is where have problem. Thanks so much for help! :)